# Prove that for $c \geq 1 \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{c} = 1$ using Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: analysis, limits

My approach was: Since $c \geq 1 \Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{c} \geq 1 \Rightarrow \sqrt[n]{c}-1 \geq 1$.

Therefore I need to find an $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n \geq N: |\sqrt[n]{c}-1|= \sqrt[n]{c}-1 \leq \epsilon, \forall \epsilon \gt 0$.

Now my problem is that I don't know how to use Bernoulli's inequality in this case. If $0 \leq c \lt 1$ I could prove the limit using the inequality, but with $c \geq 1$ I get:

$$\sqrt[n]{c} \lt 1+\epsilon \equiv c < (1+\epsilon)^n$$

, but $(1+\epsilon)^n \geq 1+n\epsilon$, so I cannot solve for n.

Does anybody have some hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $c=1+d$. Then we by Bernoulli's Inequality have 
$$1\le (1+d)^{1/n}\le 1+\frac{d}{n}.$$

Now, given $\epsilon$, it should not be hard to find an appropriate $N$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sqrt[n]{c} = 1+x_n$. Then Bernoulli says $c=(1+x_n)^n\geq 1+nx_n$. So $0\leq x_n \leq \frac{c-1}{n}$, which shows that $x_n\to 0$.